# Callback function not getting updated state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, socket.io, closures

I dont know why my `disconnectSocket()` callback function not receiving updated state which is called by `useWindowUnloadEffect()` hook.once user is updated i can see updated value in console.log.

When i am about to reload page currentUser has some value  eg. {name:'john'} its not null.

```
//App.tsx

function App() {
  const { currentUser } = useContext(UserContext);


  console.log(currentUser); //working

 function disconnectSocket() {
  socket.emit("disconnected", {
      room: "room_1",
      user: currentUser?.name,
      test: "hi",
    });
}

  useWindowUnloadEffect(disconnectSocket);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.connect();

    socket.on("connect", () => console.log("connected!"));

    socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
      if (reason === "io server disconnect") {
        // the disconnection was initiated by the server, you need to reconnect manually
        alert("Player left");
      }
    });
    return () => {
      socket.connected && socket.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;
```

```
//useWindowUnloadEffect.tsx


import { useEffect } from "react";
type HandlerType = () => void;

const useWindowUnloadEffect = (handler: HandlerType) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handler);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handler);
    };
  }, []);
};

export default useWindowUnloadEffect;
```

```
//UserContext.tsx

import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

interface User {
  name: string;
}

interface UserContextType {
  currentUser: User | null;
  setCurrentUser: (user: User | null) => void;
}

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export const UserContext = createContext<UserContextType>({
  currentUser: null,
  setCurrentUser: () => {},
});

export const UserProvider: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
  console.log(currentUser);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ currentUser, setCurrentUser }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

```
//server.js

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:5173",
  },
});
const room = "room_1";

app.use(cors());
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("join_room", async (data) => {
    const user = {
      username: data.data.username,
      room: room,
      id: socket.id,
    };
    socket.data.user = user;
    // io.sockets.adapter.rooms.forEach((q, r) => {
    //   if (io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(r).size === 1) {
    //     available_rooms = r;
    //     return;
    //   }
    // });

    socket.join(room);
    if (io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(room).size === 2) {
      let users = await io.in(room).fetchSockets();
      io.in(room).emit(
        "found-player",
        users.map((s) => s.data)
      );
      io.in(room).emit("start_game", {
        data: { word: "ABCD", defination: "word defination" },
      });
    }
  });
  socket.on("user_guess", ({ user, room, guess }) => {
    io.in(room).emit("user_guess", {
      data: { username: user, guess },
    });
  });
  socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
    if (reason && reason === "client namespace disconnect") {
      console.log(reason);
    }
  });
  socket.on("disconnected", (data) => {
    console.log("user disconnected", data);
    io.in(data.room).disconnectSockets(true);
  });
});

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

i already serached for this issue but i havent found any solution

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the dependencies! The call `useEffect(() => { ... }, [])` in `useWindowUnloadEffect` has an empty dependencies array. So, React thinks it does not depend on any external values - which is wrong, the `handler` depends on the `currentUser.name`. Because of that, React keeps using the callback passed to `useEffect` the very first time it was called, the one that has a closure with the very first value of `currentUser.name`, causing the bug you observe.

Change `useWindowUnloadEffect` as:

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
type HandlerType = () => void;

const useWindowUnloadEffect = (handler: HandlerType, dependencies: any[]) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handler);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handler);
    };
  }, dependencies);
};

export default useWindowUnloadEffect;
```

and use it as:

```js
useWindowUnloadEffect(disconnectSocket, [currentUser?.name]);
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply,but still not working

Comment: i added localStorage.setItem("ggdfgdf", JSON.stringify(currentUser)); inside  disconnectSocket and value is updated to latest but socket is still not  aware of it somehow

Comment: There may be something more missing, or I may be downright wrong. Can you share an online minimal example that reproduces the error to investigate further?

Comment: https://github.com/PrasadBroo/word_guess_game

Comment: That's hard to test without the server. Still, an online example (e.g. https://codesandbox.io/) would be better.

Comment: here it is  and i also addedserver code in the main post https://codesandbox.io/p/github/PrasadBroo/word_guess_game/